# A factor missing in output of testInteractions() from the phia package in R

Tags: r, anova

edit - seems the package is working fine and I just didn't understand what it's doing.

I am attempting to perform an analysis of simple effects in R. The phia package provides functionality for this kind of analysis using the testInteractions() function, detailed [here in section 3.3](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/phia/vignettes/phia.pdf)

I can follow the example and get the expected result:

```
> mod.boik <- lm(edr ~ therapy*medication, data=Boik)
> testInteractions(mod.boik, fixed="therapy", across="medication")
```

Outputs:

```
F Test: 
P-value adjustment method: holm
          medication1 medication2 medication3 Df Sum of Sq       F    Pr(>F)    
control        2.3006     -0.4008     -1.8999  3     54.38  0.9465    0.4239    
     T1       30.9000     19.2010      9.5009  3   3153.95 54.8985 < 2.2e-16 ***
     T2       12.9996      6.3997      3.8007  3    538.99  9.3818 7.117e-05 ***
Residuals                                     60   1149.01                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

All three levels of the therapy factor and all three levels of the medication factor.

But when I use my data:

```
age tx  score
ten day 21
ten day 27
ten day 23
ten day 28
ten day 20
ten arthur  24
ten arthur  32
ten arthur  30
ten arthur  35
ten arthur  32
ten learning    19
ten learning    30
ten learning    27
ten learning    20
ten learning    21
twelve  day 18
twelve  day 25
twelve  day 27
twelve  day 20
twelve  day 23
twelve  arthur  24
twelve  arthur  16
twelve  arthur  18
twelve  arthur  19
twelve  arthur  20
twelve  learning    34
twelve  learning    28
twelve  learning    21
twelve  learning    30
twelve  learning    29
```

Like so:

```
> mod.dataset <- lm(score ~ tx * age, data = dataset)
> testInteractions(mod.dataset, fixed="tx", across="age", adjustment="none")
```

One of the across factors gets dropped...

```
F Test: 
P-value adjustment method: none
          Value Df Sum of Sq       F    Pr(>F)    
  arthur   11.2  1     313.6 19.3580 0.0001911 ***
     day    1.2  1       3.6  0.2222 0.6416091    
learning   -5.0  1      62.5  3.8580 0.0611914 .  
Residuals       24     388.8                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

...whichever way I do it:

```
> testInteractions(mod.dataset, fixed="age", across="tx")
F Test: 
P-value adjustment method: holm
           tx1  tx2 Df Sum of Sq      F  Pr(>F)  
   ten     7.2  0.4  2    163.73 5.0535 0.01474 *
twelve    -9.0 -5.8  2    208.13 6.4239 0.01166 *
Residuals           24    388.80                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

However, the anova() function works with my data just fine:

```
> anova(mod.dataset)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: score
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
tx         2  37.80  18.900  1.1667 0.3284467    
age        1  45.63  45.633  2.8169 0.1062539    
tx:age     2 334.07 167.033 10.3107 0.0005862 ***
Residuals 24 388.80  16.200                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I would be very grateful for any clues on how I might troubleshoot this or what I might be doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: `Medication` looks like it has 4 levels, check `str(Boik)`.

Comment: Alex - thank you. That at least tells me things are behaving consistently. I think this means the problem here is my understanding of the statistical concepts involved. And I know how to address that.